# Query to get record of most recent date

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I want to fetch the record from DB on basis of most recent date (latest date).
I have written one query down below which is not working and showing error :

> 11:55:05  select firstName,lastName from mb_orderhistory where
>   eventType="PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT" and      orderId=80822 and
>   MAX(updatedDate) GROUP BY orderId Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of
>   group function    0.015 sec

This is the query which i have written.

```
select firstName,lastName from mb_orderhistory where eventType="PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT" and 
                orderId=80822 and MAX(updatedDate) GROUP BY orderId;
```

Comment: Which datatype you used for "updatedDate" ? @Akash

Comment: datatype is 'date'

Comment: You can try to use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`. Another option is to write a subquery with `MAX` in `SELECT` - clause.

Comment: Check my answer. It might be helpful to you. @Akash

Comment: I am not using `ORDER BY` then also i am getting the same error. Can you please give me some example how to use `MAX` with `SELECT` ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = (SELECT MAX(column) FROM table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an aggregate (aka group) function — like MAX — in a WHERE clause. That's because the WHERE clause is evaluated against every possible row, whereas the aggregate function's value is only defined after you've seen all of the matching rows.

See MySQL's [docs on SELECT syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), and specifically:

> In the WHERE expression, you can use any of the functions and operators that MySQL supports, except for aggregate (summary) functions.

Instead, you should just order by the updateDate (in descending order, such that the first row that's outputted is the greatest), and use LIMIT to get only one row:

```
SELECT ... WHERE orderId=80822 ... ORDER BY updatedDate DESC LIMIT 1
```

(A GROUP BY on a column doesn't make much sense if you also have an equality predicate on that column (`orderId=80822`). The predicate means that you will only have one group, and you'll know its value: in this case, 80822. The whole purpose of a GROUP BY is to identify groups; if you already know the group, you don't need it.)

Comment: `SELECT firstName,lastName
 FROM mb_orderhistory WHERE updatedDate IN (
    SELECT MAX(updatedDate)
      FROM mb_orderhistory WHERE orderId =80822 and eventType="PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT"
  );` Worked fine for me

Comment: Using a subselect like that will work, but it's likely to be less efficient. You can use EXPLAIN to try and figure out if it is, though reading the explain's output isn't easy.

Comment: `select firstName,lastName from mb_orderhistory where eventType="PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT" and 
    orderId=80822 ORDER BY updatedDate DESC LIMIT 1;` It worked very well

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use order by like `select top 1 firstname,lastname from <table_name> where <condition> order by updateddate desc`

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
select
   firstName
  ,lastName
from mb_orderhistory
where eventType = "PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT"
  and orderId = 80822
  and updateDate = (select max(updateDate) from mb_orderhistory where eventType = "PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT" and orderId = 80822)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select firstName,lastName 
From mb_orderhistory 
where eventType="PROPOSED_ITEM_EDIT" 
   and orderId=80822 
   and updatedDate = (SELECT MAX(updatedDate) FROM mb_orderhistory)
GROUP BY orderId;
```

This might be helpful to you! Tx.